# My usb mouse does not work on bootup. How do I turn off and on the external usb hub it's connected to?

Tags: linux, usb, mouse

My mouse recently started acting up, and does not work on boot up. I have to unplug and replug the device into the external usb hub I'm using to reenable it. So I'm looking to doing it from the commandline by turning off the hub and back on again.

I've followed different suggestions to turning off and on a usb device, such as `echo "1-2" > unbind ; sleep 2 ; echo "1-2" > bind`, and `echo 0 > authorized`. But when I check using lsusb, the device number of that external usb hub never changes. If I manually pull out the usb hub device and reinsert it, the device number changes, and everything is working fine.

How do I turn off the usb hub and back on again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your mouse requires an actual power off/on cycle to recover from whatever is causing it to hang. **If** your external USB hub supports port power control, then the `uhubctl` command might be able to satisfy your requirement.

Depending on your distribution, you might need to install a package to get that command. On Debian and related distributions, the package name is the same as the command name, so `sudo apt install uhubctl` should ensure it's installed.

If your distribution does not include that command (or if the available version is very old and you want to try a newer one), then you might get [the source code from GitHub](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) and build it yourself.

If you run `sudo uhubctl` without any parameters, it will display any USB hubs/ports that claim to offer the power control capability. Based on the information in your question, something like `sudo uhubctl -l 1-2 -a 2` might power-cycle your mouse, or possibly all the ports in the hub the mouse is plugged in.

The GitHub page linked above also includes usage examples and a Frequently Asked Questions list, so you might want to read it if you have trouble using the command.